# Redirecting stderr to multiple streams

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand how a part of a Bash script works. Relevant code is:

`sqlprogram -f $filename.sql > $date.log 2>&1`

It looks like if there's no error with the `sqlprogram -f $filename.sql` part, then the contents of `stdout` are written to `$date.log` but if there is an error, then `stderr` is written to `$date.log`. So basically, one of `stderr` and `stdout` is written to `$date.log`. Is that correct?

How do I redirect `stderr` to another file as well, say `$errorlog.file`? I've tried playing around with `tee` but struggled for a bit

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
sqlprogram -f "$filename.sql"  >info.log 2>error.log
```

will redirect `stdout` to `info.log` file and `stderr` to `error.log` file.

The part of your command `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect `stderr` (file descriptor `2`) to file descriptor `1` (which is `stdout`).

To redirect `stdout` to `info.log`, and `stderr` to both `info.log` and `error.log`, you can use this:

```
sqlprogram -f "$filename.sql"  >info.log 2> >(tee error.log)
```

Comment: How do I redirect stderr to both `error.log` and `&1`?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`>` redirect standard output, `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard output. All the output (regardless of whether there's an error or not) goes to the file specified, as well as anything normally printed to stderr - usually errors, but some programs also output warnings, diagnostic messages, or debugging information to stderr.

If you want to save stderr to a different file, use

```
program > $date.log 2> different-file
```

To save stderr to both the file where stdout goes *and* a different one, use

```
program > log 2> >(tee different-file >&1)
```

To save stdout to a file and output stderr to itself and a different file, use

```
program > log 2> >(tee different-file >&2)
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to the first option you wrote out, but just redirect stderr to stdout as well. So something that kind of looks like `program > $date.log 2> different-file 2>&1`

Comment: That wouldn't work, the second redirection of stderr would cancel the first. Have you tried the second option?

Comment: Yeah I did try the second option, but it redirects stderr to both `different-file` and `log`

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted?